# Reusable screens in Silverlight and XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, inheritance, silverlight-5.0

In our project we have to define 15 screens for CRUD operations on core tables.

I want to define 1 screen with a list, navigation and UI markup just once, and want to re-use these screen for every CRUD table.

What is the best approach to achieve this?

I tried inheritance, but caught up with XAML that doesn't allow inheritance (I checked several approaches on the internet/blogs, but couldn't get a good result).

Comment: If you are building a CRUD app, did you consider Lightswitch? http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch A very fast way to generate a (Silverlight) CRUD application.

Comment: We already have chosen a framework set: SL5, Prism 4.1

Answer (score 1):

The best way to cope with this is to use Styles, UserControls and possibly Templates to maximize re-use.

The only way to prevent having to define all those UI's is by generating them (design-time or run-time).

Lightswitch is a generator that can do (could have done) this for you.

You can also create your own UI Framework which creates the UI based on meta data but that might be too costly.